# PHP + JavaScript + MYSQL. Submitting text with check box values into separate databases

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, button, checkbox

just having some trouble with a webpage I'm developing. Its a cinema seating reservation system.

At the moment i am using check boxes to represent the seats. These check boxes will be ticked and confirmed with this button and function. It will Update the status of the seat in its table using code on the page its sent too.

```
<input type='button' value='Confirm Reservation' onclick='confirmReservation()'/>  

        function confirmReservation() {

        var selectedList = getSelectedList('Confirm Reservation');

        if (selectedList) {
            if (confirm('Do you want to CONFIRM this Reservation :  ' + selectedList + '?')) { 
                document.forms[0].statusA.value=0;
                document.forms[0].statusB.value=1;
                document.forms[0].action='bookingQueries.php';
                document.forms[0].submit();
            } else {
                clearSelection();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I'm trying to add a text form that the persons Name can be entered into and sent to a separate table storing the booking Information. I would like to do this using the same 'Confirm button' used for the check boxes. Iv looked around and still haven't found a way of doing this.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the form HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form with

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

All inputs which are between the two form tags are send to "bookingQueries.php"
So to save names, you have to had some treatments into the PHP file.
Something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO yourtable (seatNumber, personName) VALUES ";
$separator ='';
for($i=0; $i<=$nbSeats; $i++) {
    $query .=" (".$i.",".$_POST['nameSeat'.$i].")".$separator;
    $separator = ',';
}
//Exec query
```